# How to specify notification attributes via toArray / toDatabase function in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, notifications, eloquent, laravel-5.3

Laravel's [Notification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications) allows saving data in a `notifications` table using `toArray` or `toDatabase`. But the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#database-notifications) doesn't clarify 2 things.

1. What is the difference between `toArray()` and `toDatabase()` when it comes to storing data in the `notifications` table?
2. I have added an additional attribute (`link`) to `notifications` table, but when I do:

   ```
   public function toDatabase() {
       return [
           'data'=>'My Data',
           'link'=>'My Link'
       ];
   }
   ```

I end up getting the array serialized under the `data` attribute. What is the proper way to save the attributes using the `toArray()` or `toDatabase()` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) The method used is determined by your via() return array:

```
return ['mail', 'database', 'broadcast'];
```

When you ONLY use the toArray it will use that single data array for the Database and Broadcast notification. If you wish to define separate arrays for each then you can define the toDatabase() and toBroadcast() methods.

2) As notifications is built into the core of Laravel - there is no easy way to alter its Model - ie add that addition fillable field.
Notifications wants you to add that addition fields to the "data" array. Which by the way can still be accessed via:

```
$notification->my_custom_data_value
```